# Python how to convert the second value in a list to int

Tags: python, if-statement

I am presently building a simple program that will determine a person's horoscope sign depending on the month and date they assign.

I am running into issues checking the 2nd value in a list, I have to convert only the second value to an int.

Here is what I have so far:

```
user_day_month = input("Enter your birth month and day").lower().split(' ')
print(user_day_month)
user_sign = ""

if (user_day_month[0]=="january" and user_day_month[1]>=20) or (user_day_month[0]=="february" and user_day_month[1]<=18):
    user_sign = "Aquarius"
    print(user_sign)

elif (user_day_month[0]=="february" and user_day_month[1]>=19) or (user_day_month[0]=="march" and user_day_month[1]<=20):
    user_sign = "Pisces"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unpack the user's input into two separate named variables, and then convert one of them to an integer:

```
month, day = input("Enter your birth month and day").lower().split(' ')
day = int(day)
```

You can then refer to each of these variables directly:

```
if (month=='january' and day>=20) or...
```

The messier, more repetitive alternative would be to convert the day to an integer within the `if` statement:

```
if (user_day_month[0]=='january' and int(user_day_month[1]>=20)) or...
```

That's not the best option, as you end up casting with `int` multiple times. The first option is much cleaner.

As an intermediate possibility, you could access the list of user input and convert that value:

```
user_day_month = input("Enter your birth month and day").lower().split(' ')
user_day_month[1] = int(user_day_month[1])
```

And then use your original `if` statements:

```
if (user_day_month[0]=="january" and user_day_month[1]>=20) or...
```

But the first option is best.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to use the solution above but the line

```
month, day = input("Enter your birth month and day").lower().split(' ')
```

really confused me. I don't know what type of input console expects from me. I tried different tactics like putting space between or putting nothing or putting a comma... Didn't work for me.

What I recommend is separate your inputs into two different variables line that:

```
day = int(input("Input the day when you were born: ")) # this will be an integer
mon = input("Input the month when you were born: ").lower() # this will be a string
```

If it is essential for you to have those in an array, you can do this:

```
dateofbirth = [ int(input("Input the day when you were born: ")), input("Input the month when you were born: ").lower() ]
```

Now you could easily acces those using [ ].

```
>>> Input the day when you were born: 23
>>> Input the month when you were born: December 
>>> dateofbirth[0]
23 
>>> dateofbirth[1]
'december'
```

> Some advice about the months below

As we have total of 12 signs and your `if` statement consists of comparing the date and month of birth with some key values to determine the sign of a person you'll have to type in approximately 22 different months in your `if else` statements.

That's what I mean:

```
if (user_day_month[0]=="january" and user_day_month[1]>=20) or (user_day_month[0]=="february" and user_day_month[1]<=18):
    user_sign = "Aquarius"
    print(user_sign)

elif (user_day_month[0]=="february" and user_day_month[1]>=19) or (user_day_month[0]=="march" and user_day_month[1]<=20):
    user_sign = "Pisces"
```

That's from your example and here at some point you've already typed in "january", "february" and "february" again. I can predict that you'll continue doing this which is long, boring and inefficient.

> Better create an array of months like that:

```
months = [ None, "january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december" ]
```

Adding `None` as the first item will allow you to call months normally, according to their numbers in the calendar. January, for instance will be `months[1]` as always.

Using this construct will allow you to shorten your conditional statements and illuminate spelling errors.

```
if (month == months[1] and day >= 19) or (month == months[2] and day <= 20): 
    sign = "Pisces"
    print(sign)
```